# Need to downgrade Apache 2.25 to 2.8x and looking for precautions

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion

Web Stack:
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
Web Server: Apache 2.25
ColdFusion 9

The mod_deflate.so is causing apache to crash and restart every 3-5 seconds which is obviously hurting server performance. On another server, we are running 2.8x and are not having this problem. We are highly considering downgrading the Apache 2.25 to 2.8x. Without the deflate switch, pages are taking too long to load (faster server is taking nearly twice as long to deliver a page as an older server). I wanted to find out if we uninstall Apache and reinstall Apache, will we also need to reinstall ColdFusion? Mainly looking at downtime perspective but if there are other "gotchas" or things we should back up prior, that information woudl be great to know. Also, we do have SSL installed on a couple of sites - would we have to reinstall those as well?

Or if you have any suggestions on the mod_deflate.so and how we can fix that issue, that would also be helpful but I've worn google out trying to find how to fix it with no lasting success.

Comment: I would advise to backup the `httpd.conf` file before uninstalling apache. After reinstalling the other version you compare/merge the new file and the one you saved before. Remember to check `vhosts.conf` and the other conf files.
Coldfusion does not have to be reinstalled. You have to setup the connector. To do this - as windows administrator - you have to call `wsconfig.exe`.
You maybe execute wsconfig before uninstalling apache to remove the connector to make sure no dummy setup remains.

Comment: @bardware Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it.